# Submit button on Visualforce action page

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

I have a visual force page( page A ) that is overridding the custom object(Object A) New button which enable the new button on Object A Listview page. This page is also linked up with a publisher action. When I click on new button in the list view page there is no submit button on the title bar however, when click on button in the Publisher to bring up the page there is a submit button on top. Is there any way to enable submit button on the visual force page when user click on the new button?

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce1 has built in buttons for publisher actions. If you attempt to use a Publisher Action, the top of the Salesforce1 app will look like (on a custom publisher action - Share is Submit):

[image: Publisher Action]

Those buttons are built in as part of the Publisher. If you simply access a Visualforce page on Salesforce1, you will get a header that looks like:

[image: Just Visualforce]

The reason for this is the header is controlled by how the page is accessed. Even though the underlying page is the same, the container is different (publisher action vs Visualforce page). As far as I know, there is no way to put a Submit button in the header in just Visualforce. You will have to create your own button and have it be part of the page. This is also something that you will need to do for the desktop. There is no default Submit button available in a custom publisher action on the desktop so you have to include one as part of your Visualforce and dynamically hide it when you are using Salesforce1.

Comment: Make sense. But when you click on the "New" button on the Account list view in the salesforce1 you get similar page( popup) with "cancel/save" button. I am not sure if I have access to that

Comment: Any idea on this one as it does come with save/cancel button when clicking on new on account list view

Comment: @user3211 the New button for the Account does not use a Visualforce page. I believe the standard page layout has those buttons available, but once you override it with Visualforce those buttons are gone.

Comment: I'm using Salesforce1 and Global Action to access a VF page and my header includes the Submit button, but it is inactive (darkened).  I would love to be able to activate it by tying it to the VF actions.